# Win Server 2012 Killing my Processes. Java

Tags: java

I have an application that creates processes.
It worked perfectly for me on: Windows 10, Ubuntu.
But does not want to work on Windows Server 2012.

The application after opening the graphical interface starts the processes and it succeeds in the above described OS. But not on Win Server 2012.
Once it starts he is immediately killed. But if you open the same process manually - everything will work correctly.
How can I fix this?

Java 9.

Comment: Win 2012 core or full fledged? Which Java version? You should edit your question and add more details on your Java program, how you start it and the environment (Windows and Java).

Comment: is this service or run jar file, can you see any exception in java console

Comment: There are no mistakes. Windows simple kills the process after launch. I updated the cap, added information.